# Is it possible to add new objects in Alfresco RM (Governance Services

Tags: alfresco

I know it's possible to add models for content in Alfresco, yet, I haven't seen where you can add custom objects in Alfresco Record Management (now called Alfresco Governance Services) :

[I would like to add new types/models of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xqgu.png)